# Creating structureonly copy of SQLserver table in MS Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, structure

I am looking for ideas on how to copy the structure of a table in a SQL database as another table in the same database.

I have a SQL database (statistics) which holds a number of large transactional tables (i.e. well above 2Gb) which are linked to my Access database. Periodically I need to archive the current data and create a new table with the same structure also in the SQL database.

I can navigate from CurrentDb via from "tbl LESSON SESSION DETAILS" link to the underlying SQL ""dbo.tbl LESSON SESSION DETAILS" table and the connection string to the SQL database.

I have looked at using DoCmd.TransferDatabase to achieve the result using the following code:-

```
dbsA As Database

sTableName = "tbl LESSON SESSION DETAILS"
dbType = "ODBC Database"
sDatabasePath = CurrentDb.TableDefs(sTableName).Connect
Set dbsA = DBEngine(0).OpenDatabase("MyDB", dbDriverCompleteRequired, _
             False, sDatabasePath)
sTableName = dbsA.TableDefs(sTableName).Name
sTableNameNew =  sTableName & "_New"

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, dbType, _
      strTAbleName, acTable, dbsA, sTableNameNew, structureonly:=True
```

However when I run this code it fails as 'acExport' is expecting sTableName to be in the CurrentDB and  sTableNameNew to be in the dbsA database. Changing CurrentDb might be one option but I have not found any ideas on how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Write a stored procedure on the database end:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * INTO [tbl_LESSON_SESSION_DETAILS_NEW] FROM [tbl_LESSON_SESSION_DETAILS];
DELETE FROM [tbl_LESSON_SESSION_DETAILS_NEW];
```

Then just execute the stored proc from your code.  You can replace the table names /w variables then from your code you can name the new table anything you like.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258259(v=sql.80).aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306574

You may want to consider keeping your pointers the original table and just archive it to a new "backup" version, then wipe it clean:

```
SELECT * INTO [tbl_LESSON_SESSION_DETAILS_BAK_05152011] FROM [tbl_LESSION_SESSION_DETAILS];
DELETE [FROM tbl_LESSION_SESSION_DETAILS];
```

probably want to beef up that a bit to make *really sure* you've still got the data in the new table before you delete it from the original...

Comment: The above example was VB.NET, here is VBA:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185125

Answer (score 0):

You have some arguments in the wrong order. You've mixed database name and the source argument. Try this:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, dbType, strTAbleName, acTable, dbsA, sTableNameNew, structureonly:=True
```